# How do I get the bag-of-words representation of document content with Whoosh?

Tags: python, whoosh

I have an index schema like the following:

```
schema = Schema(
    title=TEXT(stored=True),
    content=TEXT,
    id=ID,
    topicID=NUMERIC,
)
```

I first get documents for topic `t` using `searcher.documents(topicID=t)`.  This returns hits.  I'd like to get the bag-of-words representation of the hits' `content` field.  For instance `[(u'This',1),(u'is',1),(u'a',1),(u'document',1)]` when `content=u'This is a document'`.

If there is a way to get the bag-of-words representation (or TF-IDF) more generally in Whoosh - perhaps of documents rather than hits - that is acceptable as well.

EDIT: I'd like a solution that preprocesses the bag-of-words/TF-IDF on indexing, and then getting the representation is a one-liner function or variable.  Instead of doing the processing live, each time I want the representation.

Answer (score 2):

There are implemented functions for this in [`whoosh.reading.IndexReader`](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/reading.html#whoosh.reading.IndexReader):

- [`whoosh.reading.IndexReader.frequency(fieldname, text)`](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/reading.html#whoosh.reading.IndexReader.frequency)

  > Returns the total number of instances of the given term in the
  >   collection.
- [`whoosh.reading.IndexReader.doc_frequency(fieldname, text)`](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/reading.html#whoosh.reading.IndexReader.doc_frequency)

  > Returns how many documents the given term appears in.

To iterate through the list of all indexed terms use:

- [`whoosh.reading.IndexReader.all_terms()`](https://whoosh.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/reading.html#whoosh.reading.IndexReader.all_terms)

  > Yields (fieldname, text) tuples for every term in the index.

Comment: Thanks!  While this is close, this doesn't seem to directly return the representation that I specified above.  Again, what is desirable is a solution where the TF-IDF or BOW is stored in preprocessing or is retrievable in a one-liner.  Not obtained through iteration.

Comment: You should write a function that iterate your words and use `Your_reader.frequency('content', 'document')` to get their frequencies.

Comment: This answer is missing two things, which I combined to make the TF-IDF work.  ` content=TEXT(stored=True,vector=Frequency()),` and `docnum = searcher.document_number(id=docid); print [doccount for doccount in searcher.vector(docnum,"content").items_as("frequency")]`.  This gives the BOW for a single document.

Comment: @Matt, feel free to add your example to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Counter for that:

```
from collections import Counter

bow = Counter(content.split())
```

gives

```
Counter({'This': 1, 'a': 1, 'is': 1, 'document': 1})
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is the documentation for it.

Edit: Forgot some brackets

Comment: Nice. :)  Though it's unfortunately not what I want.  Sorry, I should've clarified that I'm looking for a solution that does all the processing at the time of indexing, so that little computing time is spent on getting the representation when I ask for it after indexing (e.g. saying something like `content._bow` vs. `Counter(content.split())`)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond. what you could do is overwrite your local Whoosh files and change the return of the function in question. Or you could inherit the function in your code and overwrite the return from there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not 100% clear on how to do this.  Do you have code that demonstrates?